# How to make CasperJS work with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, browserify

I've successfully used [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) to simulate browsing, to scrap websites, and to make screenshots.

I need to do this for websites built with [browserify](http://browserify.org/) too, but I can't manage to make `casperjs` evaluate their page's javascript code.

For instance, let's say I want to make a screenshot of this browserify demo page : `http://requirebin.com/embed?gist=maxogden/9576799`

Here is a code that *should* theoretically work but doesn't :

```js
// initialize casper
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'
    }
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

var url = 'http://requirebin.com/embed?gist=maxogden/9576799';

// start browsing
casper.start(url, function() {
    this.viewport(1600, 900);
    this.wait(2000, function() { // <-- let's wait a long time, to be sure the js is executed...
        this.capture('screenshot.png'); // <-- Proof of the error
    });
    this.capture('screenshot.png'); // <-- Proof of the non (browserify) js evaluation
});

casper.run();
```

When running it (`casperjs errorsample.js`), it throws the following error :

```js
Page Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

I suspect a conflict between the different `require()` functions from `browserify`, `casperjs` and `nodejs`, but I'm not sure about it.

Does anyone have a solution or a workaround ?

Comment: No, PhantomJS' require is not available in the page context. wait() is an asynchronous step function, so you should put the evaluate() block into the wait() then function.

Comment: I edited the code, thanks. Do you have an idea on why it doesn’t work, then ?

Comment: Also register to the "resource.error" event. Might be an SSL error. Try running CasperJS with the --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any arguments

Comment: Actually, I had already tried with these arguments on some other browserify-powered SSL websites (such as facebook.com) with no results. It does not nothing here either.

Comment: (1) Does the `casper.on("resource.error", function(msg){...})` turn up anything? (2) Have you tried adding `--web-security=false`? Please note that all of those commandline option must go between the casperjs and your script file: `casperjs <here> script.js`

Comment: (1) No, nothing. (2) I had not, but it doesn't change anything. (`casperjs --web-security=false --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any myscript.js`)

Comment: I just ran your code. It works with CasperJS 1.1-beta3+ with PhantomJS 2.0.0 as-is without any additional commandline arguments. When I change to PhantomJS 1.9.7, I only need to include the `--ssl-protocol=any` commandline option. I'm on windows, but I think it will be exactly the same on linux.

Comment: Weird, on my computer (OS: Mac OS X Yosemite; PhantomJS version : 1.9.8; CasperJS version : 1.1.0-beta3) I don't get the gradients squares from the example page in the screenshot.
I'll try on linux and/or windows, tomorrow, if it works there !